# Is there a way for server-side php to see HTML attributes?

Tags: php, html, server-side

I want to make a reusable form validation system, similar to something that would be implemented in Javascript. Ideally I could use things like class names or input types from form elements to decide what validation tests to apply.

Is there a way to implement this in PHP? That is: Is there anyway to get a hold of these HTML attributes on the server-side?

Comment: Do it the other way: use PHP to determine the validation and HTML attributes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Could you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: Brief example, something like: `$field['user_email']['attrs'] = array('required' => true, 'type' => 'email', 'minlength' => 3, 'matches' => 'confirm_email');` You could use this array to create your HTML/client validation and also use it to do your server side validation. You just have to write the code to do it, of course.

Comment: So does the script processing the form need to know anything from the script that created the form. That is my main limitation right now; the two scripts must be independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/domdocument). But I'm not sure I would recommend it based on what you're trying to do, as that could get pretty ugly.

I had a similar idea and asked on [StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235579/automating-form-error-handling) a while back.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a nasty hack.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the input through $_POST['field_name'] and loop through the array given by wesly murch. Add switch statements like 
if arraykey=required // doo something
arraykey=minlength=> //do something